# AppsFlyer NativeScript - Could not find : af-android-sdk-4.8.3

Tags: android, nativescript, appsflyer

I would like to use the AppsFlyer plugin for Nativescript : https://github.com/AppsFlyerSDK/nativescript-plugin-appsflyer

But when I want build the project (for Android), I have this error :

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_F0F1F2F3DebugApkCopy'.
   > Could not find :af-android-sdk-4.8.3:.
     Required by:
         project :app
```

Could anyone help me please ?

Comment: Did you make everything from README on github that you linked?

Comment: I installed the plugin : `tns plugin add nativescript-plugin-appsflyer` and just this, without use the plugin, cause this error when I compile

Comment: What about calling module and initialize the sdk? It looks like you didn't initialize sdk and plugin can't find it.

Comment: That looks like something that may be broken by the android runtime package. What's your `tns-android` version?

Comment: tns-android version 3.4.2

Answer (score 0):

I have:

```
tns --version //3.2.1
npm -v        //5.6.0
node -v       //7.2.1
```

Steps:

```
$ tns create HelloWorld --template nativescript-template-tutorial
$ cd HelloWorld/

$ tns plugin add nativescript-plugin-appsflyer
+ nativescript-plugin-appsflyer@1.0.10
added 1 package in 5.066s
Successfully installed plugin nativescript-plugin-appsflyer.
```

Open `main-page.js` and change to following:

```
exports.pageLoaded = function() {

var appsFlyer = require("nativescript-plugin-appsflyer");

console.log("FESS :: call initSdk ... ");

        var options = {
            devKey:  'WdpTVAcYwmxsaQ4WeTspmh',
            appId: "975313579",
            isDebug: true
        };

        appsFlyer.initSdk(options).then(function(result) {
            alert("initSdkResponse: " +  result.status);
        }, function(err) {
            console.log("trackEvent :: results  ... " +  JSON.stringify(err));            
            alert("initSdkResponse: " +  JSON.stringify(err));
        });
};
```

After run:

```
$ tns run android
```

Output:

```
     Searching for devices...
Copying template files...
  ◜ Installing tns-androidInstalling  tns-android
+ tns-android@3.2.0
added 1 package in 2.689s
+ babel-traverse@6.26.0
added 24 packages in 5.856s
+ babel-types@6.26.0
updated 1 package in 1.792s
+ babylon@6.18.0
updated 1 package in 1.785s
+ lazy@1.0.11
added 1 package in 2.613s
Project successfully created.
Preparing project...
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-plugin-appsflyer for android.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-theme-core for android.
Successfully prepared plugin tns-core-modules for android.
Successfully prepared plugin tns-core-modules-widgets for android.
Gradle build...

:config phase:  createDefaultIncludeFiles

:config phase:  addAarDependencies
        +adding dependency: /Users/maxim/Appsflyer/projects/ZEVEL/NativeScriptsDemos/HelloWorld/platforms/android/libs/aar/widgets-release.aar
        +adding dependency: /Users/maxim/Appsflyer/projects/ZEVEL/NativeScriptsDemos/HelloWorld/platforms/android/libs/aar/af-android-sdk-4.8.3.aar
Project successfully prepared (Android)
Building project...
Gradle build...

:config phase:  createDefaultIncludeFiles
        +found plugins: nativescript-plugin-appsflyer
Renaming plugin directory to flavor name: /Users/maxim/Appsflyer/projects/ZEVEL/NativeScriptsDemos/HelloWorld/platforms/android/src/nativescript-plugin-appsflyer -> /Users/maxim/Appsflyer/projects/ZEVEL/NativeScriptsDemos/HelloWorld/platforms/android/src/F0
        +found plugins: tns-core-modules-widgets
         + creating include.gradle file for /Users/maxim/Appsflyer/projects/ZEVEL/NativeScriptsDemos/HelloWorld/platforms/android/configurations/tns-core-modules-widgets
Renaming plugin directory to flavor name: /Users/maxim/Appsflyer/projects/ZEVEL/NativeScriptsDemos/HelloWorld/platforms/android/src/tns-core-modules-widgets -> /Users/maxim/Appsflyer/projects/ZEVEL/NativeScriptsDemos/HelloWorld/platforms/android/src/F1

:config phase:  createPluginsConfigFile
         Creating product flavors include.gradle file in /Users/maxim/Appsflyer/projects/ZEVEL/NativeScriptsDemos/HelloWorld/platforms/android/configurations folder...

:config phase:  pluginExtend
        +applying configuration from: /Users/maxim/Appsflyer/projects/ZEVEL/NativeScriptsDemos/HelloWorld/platforms/android/configurations/nativescript-plugin-appsflyer/include.gradle
        +applying configuration from: /Users/maxim/Appsflyer/projects/ZEVEL/NativeScriptsDemos/HelloWorld/platforms/android/configurations/include.gradle
        +applying configuration from: /Users/maxim/Appsflyer/projects/ZEVEL/NativeScriptsDemos/HelloWorld/platforms/android/configurations/tns-core-modules-widgets/include.gradle

:config phase:  addAarDependencies
        +adding dependency: /Users/maxim/Appsflyer/projects/ZEVEL/NativeScriptsDemos/HelloWorld/platforms/android/libs/aar/widgets-release.aar
        +adding dependency: /Users/maxim/Appsflyer/projects/ZEVEL/NativeScriptsDemos/HelloWorld/platforms/android/libs/aar/af-android-sdk-4.8.3.aar
Running full build

Successfully synced application org.nativescript.HelloWorld on device b067ad3e.
JS: FESS :: call initSdk ... 
JS: aAF-A :: ppsFlyer.initSdk: {"devKey":"WdpTVAcYwmxsaQ4WeTspmh","appId":"975313579","isDebug":true}
JS: AppsFlyer :: NativeScript :: trackAppLaunch is called
```

Comment: I have followed your procedure, but same error. 
Versions : tns --version -> 3.4.3, npm -v -> 5.6.0, node -v -> v8.9.4
I've tried to downgrade tns to 3.2.1 but same error, again.